# How to check desired ValueMember in my ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, combobox, datatable

I am new to C#. I have one `Combo Box` `cmbDoctor`. It is binding with `DataTable`

```
display member
       --> Name
 Value Member
       -->  ID       Name ,ID are table column Names
```

My problem is that I have added a new tab `tabPageUpdate`

When I click `Specified ID` in `tabPageUpdate` I want to select `Combobox` with `display Name`

if anyone knows how to do this, please provide a solution for this.

Comment: please edit your question..people will get confuse with what you asked for

Comment: What´s "Specified ID"? Do you want to select (focus) the ComboBox, or do you want to select the combobox item with the ID that is associated with the "specified ID"? Where does it come from? What´s the code you have tried?

Comment: I got the solution. Please `don't` raise questions

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the `Text` property of the `ComboBox` and the `Value` will be set automatically.

```
cmbDoctor.Text = "Some Name";
```